# Accessing elements inside a ng-view after rendering

Tags: angularjs

After a partial is loaded from a route, is there any way to access elements (with js or scripts to be loaded when rendering is finished) that were writen inside a ng-view?

I have tried with jquery but the elements and data have not been rendered yet when/while jQuery is running.

See the example below:

**The Partial HTML File**

```html
<ul id="items">
    <li ng-repeat="item in data.items" id="data">
      <a>{{data.element}}</a>
      <a href="" class="edit"><span class="icon icon-edit"></span>edit item</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**The `ng-view` Route to the Partial File**

```
function(routeProvider, locationProvider) {
  routeProvider.when('/showData', {
    templateUrl: '/partials/partial.html',
    controller: 'Controller',
    resolve: {
      data: [
        'dataHandler',
        function (dataHandler) {
          return dataHandler.requestData();
        }
      ]
    }
  }).otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/showData'
  });

  locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
};
```

**The Controller with The script that has to access rendered data**

```
function (scope, data) {
  scope.data = data;
  $("#items").find('.edit') // returns an empty jQuery because ng-repeat directive builds DOM elements after this controller.
};
```

Comment: This question is way too vague

Comment: Directives work, jQuery would work (assuming you want to including that), standard JavaScript would work in an ng-click or other standard directive. It all depends on what you want to do!

Comment: No, i want just call a function before all data is rendered in the browser

Comment: you should use angular.element('#id') instead, and you should try with a timeout 0 at controller or better define a directive with postlink element

Comment: @whiteb0x Unconstrutive comment... if you are a javascript master, answer the question.

Comment: @JorgeGuerola i tried but this don´t solve the problem maybe ng-repeat handle some event.

Comment: Have a look at `$viewContentLoaded` event [examples](http://aleaiactaest.ch/2012/06/28/angular-js-and-dom-readyness-for-jquery/). Though I could not make it work as I need.